# Replacing my daily driver laptop - Considering Dell XPS or cheaper

Tags: laptop

I'm in the market for a new laptop to replace my aging ASUS model from 2013.

I'm looking for a thin and lightweight model, with good battery (let's say minimum 5 hours). I would also like some sort of dedicated graphics card. I'm not a huge gamer, so it doesn't need to be top of the line. The laptop will be used primarily (90%) for office productivity / video, photo editing / coding with WSL2. But I would like the ability to play something now and again if the mood strikes.

A Dell XPS with a GeForce 1650 seems like an ideal solution, but it has a pretty hefty price tag, around $2000 CAD. I'm wondering what if any alternatives I should consider that could save a few bucks.

A few other considerations:

I need a 15 inch display, 1920 x 1080 with a good color gamet. I do not need a touch screen, although I'm not opposed to one either.

I need a very large, fast hard drive (e.g. 1 TB SSD) though I'm willing to buy a model with a smaller drive and upgrade, as long as the model allows it.

I would prefer to stick Intel/Nvidia if possible. I've had three AMD laptops in the past (2006, 2009, 2011) and none of them lasted more then 2-3 years, as they all had serious over heating issues almost from Day 1. However my current Intel/Nvidia laptop from 2013 has no such issues, nor have any of the Intel-based laptops I've used for work.

WiFi 6 is highly desirable. Ethernet port and a dedicated number pad would be nice but not required.

Preferably compatible with a Dell TB16 dock.

Looking to purchase in the next 1-2 months. Dell often does a semi-annual sale in early March, so I might buy an XPS then if I don't find anything else in the meantime.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I know you said you don't want AMD.  I would have agreed with that a couple years ago however, things have changed recently.  AMD has made some major improvements and now is arguably better than Intel.  If you will consider AMD, I found a quite nice laptop for only $1,000

[https://www.amazon.com/Zephyrus-Gaming-GeForce-Windows-GA502IU-ES76/dp/B0863S8HJ3/ref=sr_1_4?dchild=1&keywords=zephyrus+g15&qid=1614029167&sr=8-4](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0863S8HJ3)

It is a gaming laptop, but it has really good specs, doesn't look that much like a gaming computer, and is still pretty thin considering the specs.

Comment: I want to second this notion, AMD CPUs are absolutely better in most ways when it comes to productivity tasks. 2011 AMD is absolutely unlike 2021 AMD. I deploy a fair few laptops for my work and I deploy AMD wherever I can as they are generally cheaper and run much cooler than an Intel equivalent.